# help with NSDateFormater

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to set the format for a given dateString but I am not able to get it working. Here is the code I am using:

> [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
>   date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-05-08 18:31:42"];

but I keep getting (null) for the date, 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When someone answers your questions you can click accept - which will give them a small reward for putting in the effort/helping. You may want to do that with some of your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hh` should be `HH`. `hh` is for 12-hour time and `HH` is 24-hour time. Here's your code with the changes:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-05-08 18:31:42"];
```